# process.mainModule is deprecated in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

```
module.exports = path.dirname(process.mainModule.filename)
```

[Main Module Deprecated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBzIV.png)

process.mainModule.filename is deprecated in nodejs.
Is there any alternative method to get a current directory of the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The entry point of the current application can be obtained by checking [`require.main.filename`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_accessing_the_main_module).
- [`__dirname` gets you the directory the module is in](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_dirname).
- [`process.cwd()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_cwd) gets the current working directory.

Chances are you want one of these.